# Getting JSON response data from server

Tags: json, swift, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to get the response error from a server in human readable format. I know there's an error, I just don't know how to parse the JSON. I am getting error **The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

This is what I am trying:

```
var request = URLRequest(url:url)
request.httpBody = "stripeToken=\(token.tokenId)&amount=\(priceInt)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    // TODO: Handle success or failure
    if let data = data {
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print("Json: \(json)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Catch Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

Response Body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "charge": "ch_1E5yhbAtWFyXMp9t5rTIyGwM",
    "code": "card_declined",
    "decline_code": "generic_decline",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/card-declined",
    "message": "Your card was declined.",
    "type": "card_error"
  }
}
```

Comment: In a POST request you might have to pass the parameters as dictionary rather than `&` separated key-value pairs. And **never** use `.mutableContainers` in Swift. It's pointless. Omit the entire `options` parameter. And `print(error)` rather than `print(error.localizedDescription)` to get more detailed information about the error.

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried passing the parameters as dictionary key value pairs and it's the same result. Still getting the error.

Comment: What do you want to know? The reason of error? or the way to parse?

Comment: `JSON` you gave looks fine

Comment: @Ryan the error is parsing the response in the right format.

Comment: `print(String(data:data, encoding:.utf8)!)` right before the `do` line. Is it really JSON?

Comment: @vadian I added that line  and put a breakpoint there, this is what I got: po data
▿ 0 bytes
  - count : 0
  ▿ pointer : 0x000000000000bad0
    - pointerValue : 47824
  - bytes : 0 elements

Comment: No breakpoint. What does the line print?

Comment: @vadian the response body in the question is the data I should be getting back from the server

Comment: @vadian that line doesn't print anything

Comment: Then you get no data and the error is caused by the URL request.

Comment: @vadian the response body in the question is the data I should be getting back from the server

Comment: Yes, you **should** but you **don't**. Once again the error is related to the URL request.